# Get current generated html while debugging mvc3 view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, debugging, razor, visual-studio-debugging

While stepping through the generation of a View.  Is there a way to see the HTML that has been generated to that point?  I've tried looking through the locals variable list, but am having trouble finding it.

Comment: As an alternative you could render a view to a string and view that way. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string

Comment: While I don't think this will solve the particular issue I was hoping for. I do have a place I can use that so thanks for the link!

Comment: @jared i think you should try to use PartailView because return type on partial view MvcHtmlString so can get all generated Html at server side for more info please refer  http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/05/15/asp-net-mvc-render-partial-view-to-string/

Comment: @Shivkumar Partial views are good for bits of HTML that you want to reuse. I don't think that converting all of my documents to partials is a good practice (for the sake of solving this problem).  Partials are good for reuse if it's not going to be reused then (in my opinion) it doesn't belong in a partial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the ViewContext.Writer.  Try adding...

```
((System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage)(this)).ViewContext.Writer
```

to your watch window.

Comment: This will allow you to see the HTML that has been generated up to any point while stepping through your view.  Have you tried it?  Any concerns with this answer?

Comment: While this code didn't work as written for me it clued me in to the solution so thanks for that.  I ended up adding a watch for `(this).ViewContext.Writer.ToString()` For whatever reason when I included the cast there was a DLL conflict.  At the bottom of my layout I included a `@if (false){}` so that I could grab the html in totality before it was returned (and obviously a break-point could be added sooner if you wanted to step through).